# How to read child nodes without mentioning parent node in firebase database within android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am making an android app using the firebase Realtime database. My rules structure is given below:

```
{
// Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
// make changes to their data

  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It means that a user should be signed in as an authenticated user to **write** some data. But when it comes to **read** no sign in is required.

Now I need to ignore the **uid** of the user to give free access to other users( i.e. without signing in).
[image]

This is the java code I am using currently to **read** data.

```
final Intent k = getIntent();
        final String school = Objects.requireNonNull(k.getExtras()).getString("School");
        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String roll = Objects.requireNonNull(i.getExtras()).getString("Roll");
 myRef = myfire.getReference("Users")
.child("GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2")// **I have problem here.**
.child(school).child(roll);
        myRef.child("basic").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb01name").getValue().toString();

                String number = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb04roll").getValue().toString();

                if(name == null){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                basic model = new basic(name,number);
                tvName.setText(name);

                tvRoll.setText(number);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

I could not decide what to write instead of the first child to **read** any data without signing in.

```
.child("GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2")
```

Please guide me **How to ignore** this child? Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**
The advice "try to refrain from using deeply nested children"  by @Abdullah Z Khan further provided me insight into the problem. I changed my codes as given below :

```
 myfire = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final Intent k = getIntent();
        final String school = Objects.requireNonNull(k.getExtras()).getString("School");
        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String roll = Objects.requireNonNull(i.getExtras()).getString("Roll");
        
//--------------------the trick----------------

        if (school.equals("224613")){
             tvSchool.setText("GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2");
        }else if (school.equals("224614")){
             tvSchool.setText("uQx5jDVRp9PV3QpM2FBU6HPq5SJ3");
        }
        final String uid = tvSchool.getText().toString();
//---------------------------------------------------
        myRef = myfire.getReference("Users").child(uid).child(roll);
        myRef.child("basic").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb01name").getValue().toString();

                String number = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb04roll").getValue().toString();

                if(name == null){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                basic model = new basic(name,number);
                tvName.setText(name);

                tvRoll.setText(number);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

Although this **PLAN B** has temporarily relieved me a bit yet the question is still unanswered.Beacuse I have to write the **uid code** of users each time they join the app( and have to update and publish the app again and again.A better solution is awaited.

Comment: Which user you want to read the data from ... if you want to ignore the user.. then which `basic` node you want to read its underlying children?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Added values in **>>>** marked lines for understanding

From what is given, this is your database structure:

```
{
    "uid": {
        "schoolId": {
            "roll": {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because it is so much nested (I'd suggest a different hierarchy altogether), there is no
***easy*** way to access a child with an unknown parent as is. However, if you can change the database structure to this:

```
{
    >>> "224614":"GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2",
    "schoolId2":"uid2",
    >>> "GcZoeK7JIbNWVOog6ZjUPiBfxwn2": {
        "224614": {
            "roll": {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get a uid lookup table. You can then use that to reach the node. Keep in mind this isn't a direct answer to what you asked, which is how to get a nested node(not value) without knowing the parent, but here you can dynamically access uids of whatever school is needed, assuming each school has exactly **one** parent.

After that, nest your listener:

```
myRef = myfire.getReference("Users");
myRef.child(school).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if  (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String uid=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    myRef.child(uid)// **I have problem here.**
                    .child(school).child(roll);
                            myRef.child("basic").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb01name").getValue().toString();

                                    String number = (String) dataSnapshot.child("fb04roll").getValue().toString();

                                    if(name == null){

                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    basic model = new basic(name,number);
                                    tvName.setText(name);

                                    tvRoll.setText(number);



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }

                            });
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

        });
```

In practice, try to refrain from using deeply nested children, rather use references to other nodes.

*I hope this helps!!*

Comment: See the last bit of code I gave and the database structure I gave. The theory is every time a school gets created, you will do 2 things. 1: create a node in "Users", where node name/key = school and node value=uid associated with that school. Then you follow the code I provided, and populate with your necessary variables

Comment: Note: the purpose of my answer was to assist the code in finding the uid from another node in the database, so you won't need to hardcode it. The first `onDataChange` will give you the uid for the school (provided you added the extra nodes in the database as I suggested).

Comment: In the `Users` node, along with the other uids. I'll update the answer with your values.

Comment: Firebase console > Realtime Database > Rules
It would help you could provide a structure of your database, a tree hierarchy because from your images I can't tell whether "Users" exists in a root node or a child node.

Comment: Because I don't know your full hierarchy, I added that portion so you can merge it yourself with your existing ruleset. For example, I can't tell if Users is in 2nd node or third, so you have to apply the appropriate cascading yourself.

Comment: Sure, where do you want to chat?

Comment: @ Abdullah Z Khan Can you see my other question **Firebase recycler View showing Error on Third Child only**

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
final Intent k = getIntent();
    final String school = Objects.requireNonNull(k.getExtras()).getString("School");
    final Intent i = getIntent();
    final String roll = Objects.requireNonNull(i.getExtras()).getString("Roll");
    myRef = myfire.getReference("Users")
    
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child(school).child(roll).child("basic").child("fb01name").getValue().toString();

            String number = (String) dataSnapshot.child(school).child(roll).child("basic").child("fb04roll").getValue().toString();

            if(name == null){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            basic model = new basic(name,number);
            tvName.setText(name);

            tvRoll.setText(number);



        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: from this line :`myfire.getReference("Users")` you get all the uids in the snapshot and then you get the children you want from the snapshot by calling the proper child(). what error did you get? maybe it can be solved.

Comment: well since you are the only person having access to your code, you need to do some debugging and tweak the code a bit so it works for you. but I am fairly sure this is the way to go with this problem

Comment: but this is not the code I have in my answer. what is the problem with my code? why not debug it and find out what values it is returning. since it doesn't crash, it means it is fetching something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I understood your question, but if you are trying to read the children of all the nodes without specifying them, you can try to do something like the code below: (I didn't test it, I just changed your sample)

```
    myRef = myfire.getReference("Users");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot keySnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot schoolSnap : keySnap.getChildren()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot rollSnap : schoolSnap.getChildren()) {
                        String mRollSnap = rollSnap.getKey();

                        String name = mRollSnap.child("basic").child("fb01name").getValue().toString();
                        String number = (String) mRollSnap.child("basic").child("fb04roll").getValue().toString();
                        if(name == null){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        basic model = new basic(name,number);
                        tvName.setText(name);
                        tvRoll.setText(number);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
    });
```